# Making dynamic forms using WTForms

Tags: flask, wtforms

I have a WTForm which currently has a selector and a submit button. I want to augment it to have the layout:

1. A selector
2. A simple button
3. A submit button

When I push the `simple button`, I should be able to add an item to a`<ol>`, and only finally submit the entire list when I hit the submit button. Multiple selection is not the answer because the same option can be chosen multiple times.

How can I do this with WTForms?

Comment: You probably need to use client side scripting, i.e., JS to get this done. There is some documentation on generating dynamic forms [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wtforms/cJl3aqzZieA) but I think ___that___ sol'n is based on forms where the dynamic elements are known PRIOR to page load. You want to know if _after_ the page is loaded whether the form can be generated. I think the answer is it can't be done with WTForms.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks.